# How can I display a '+' or '-' sign in front of a result using cell formating?

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

I'm subtracting figures and I need to show whether the result is negative or positive.

Stumped as to how to make the '+' or '-' sign appear using cell formatting. Minus is automatic, I presume, but the positive I'm struggling with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a custom number format for your cells, such as:

```
"+"0;"-"0;0
```

displays -1, 0, 1 as

```
-1, 0, +1
```

or

```
"+"0.00;"-"0.00;"No change"
```

displays -1, 0, 1 as

```
-1.00, No change, +1.00
```

Comment: Actually the "" marks around the + - are not needed.  Just use  `+0;-0;0`

Comment: Therefore could you use +??.??;-??.??;??.??. Which I hope would allow for alignment and show the +/- symbols?

Comment: As mentioned [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=69505&p=361995#post361995), you could use `+General;-General;General` to keep original decimal settings